# Redirect in same page and display message to user

Tags: php, html

I would like when the user is filling up the form and click the button to get redirected in the same page and throw him the message "Everything went well, Thank you!"

For now i only do it with `action="mail_handler.php"` but it goes to the other php file and displays the message in other blank page.

Is there any way to use the functionality of mail_handler.php but without nagivating there?
I tried `action=""` and before the button`<?php include 'mail_handler.php'; ?>` but with no success

Index.html form:

```
<!-- The Form Section -->
<div style="background-color: #5A5377" id="form_section">
    <h2 class="w3-wide" align="Center"><font color="white"><strong><br>Přihláška</strong></font></h2>
    <form align="center" name="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <ul class="errorMessages"></ul>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="fname"><font color="white"><strong>Jméno</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" required="required"><br></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="lname"><font color="white"><strong><br>Příjmení</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value required="required"div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="vysoho"><font color="white"><strong><br>Vysoká škola</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="vysoka_skola" name="vysoka_skola" value="" required="required"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="fname"><font color="white"><strong><br>Studijní obor</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="obor" name="obor" value="" required="required"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="prace"><font color="white"><strong><br>Odkaz na bakalářskou práci</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="prace" name="prace" value="" required="required"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="myfile"><font color="white"><strong><br>Bakalářská práce</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile[]" multiple="multiple" required="required"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="dropdown"><font color="white"><strong><br>Kategorie v soutěži</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <select id="kategorie" name="kategorie" required="required">
            <option value="science">Science</option>
            <option value="technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="science">Engineering</option>
            <option value="science">Mathematics</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" id="gdpr" name="gdpr" value="" required="required">
          <label for="gdpr"><font color="white"><strong> I agree with GDPR</strong></font></label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <?php include 'mail_handler.php'; ?>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Poslat"><br><br></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!--END OF FORM-->
```

mail_handler.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "alex@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['fname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lname'];
    $skola = $_POST['vysoka_skola'];
    $obor = $_POST['obor'];
    $prace = $_POST['prace'];
    $files = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $kategorie = $_POST['kategorie'];
    //echo gettype($files);
    $all_thesis_string="";
    for($index=0;$index<count($_FILES['myfile']['name']);$index++){
        $all_thesis_string.=$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$index].","; //create a string with all bachelor attachments of user
    }

    $subject = "Form submission of ".$first_name." ".$last_name;
    $message = "User Details: \n\n Jméno: $first_name \n Příjmení: $last_name \n Vysoká škola: $skola \n Studijní obor: $obor \n Odkaz na bakalářskou práci: $prace \n Kategorie: $kategorie \n Bakalářská práce: $all_thesis_string";

    $headers = "From:" . $first_name;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Přihláška úspěšně odeslána. Děkuji " . $first_name . ".\n \n";
    include 'upload.php';
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page. 
    }
?>
```

Comment: just put your HTML into your PHP and then run the PHP.

Comment: Not sure why including one into the other should _not_ work. But your second script in turn includes `upload.php`, and we don’t know what is going on in there …

Comment: _“but with no success”_ - that is not really _useful_ information; please give a _proper_ problem description in cases like this. What happened instead of what you expected to happen, what errors did you get, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ken Lee suggested in the comments, the best way of doing this is to use mail_handler.php itself as a form action. This will become your **index.php:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "alex@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['fname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lname'];
    $skola = $_POST['vysoka_skola'];
    $obor = $_POST['obor'];
    $prace = $_POST['prace'];
    $files = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $kategorie = $_POST['kategorie'];
    //echo gettype($files);
    $all_thesis_string="";
    for($index=0;$index<count($_FILES['myfile']['name']);$index++){
        $all_thesis_string.=$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$index].","; //create a string with all bachelor attachments of user
    }

    $subject = "Form submission of ".$first_name." ".$last_name;
    $message = "User Details: \n\n Jméno: $first_name \n Příjmení: $last_name \n Vysoká škola: $skola \n Studijní obor: $obor \n Odkaz na bakalářskou práci: $prace \n Kategorie: $kategorie \n Bakalářská práce: $all_thesis_string";

    $headers = "From:" . $first_name;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Přihláška úspěšně odeslána. Děkuji " . $first_name . ".\n \n";
    include 'upload.php';
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page. 
    }
?>
<!-- The Form Section -->
<div style="background-color: #5A5377" id="form_section">
    <h2 class="w3-wide" align="Center"><font color="white"><strong><br>Přihláška</strong></font></h2>
    <form align="center" name="form1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <ul class="errorMessages"></ul>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="fname"><font color="white"><strong>Jméno</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" required="required"><br></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="lname"><font color="white"><strong><br>Příjmení</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value required="required"div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="vysoho"><font color="white"><strong><br>Vysoká škola</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="vysoka_skola" name="vysoka_skola" value="" required="required"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="fname"><font color="white"><strong><br>Studijní obor</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="obor" name="obor" value="" required="required"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="prace"><font color="white"><strong><br>Odkaz na bakalářskou práci</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="prace" name="prace" value="" required="required"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="myfile"><font color="white"><strong><br>Bakalářská práce</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile[]" multiple="multiple" required="required"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="dropdown"><font color="white"><strong><br>Kategorie v soutěži</strong></font></label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <select id="kategorie" name="kategorie" required="required">
            <option value="science">Science</option>
            <option value="technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="science">Engineering</option>
            <option value="science">Mathematics</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" id="gdpr" name="gdpr" value="" required="required">
          <label for="gdpr"><font color="white"><strong> I agree with GDPR</strong></font></label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Poslat"><br><br></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!--END OF FORM-->
```

In the PHP script you can display whatever message you want to by just adding `echo`

Your second option is to target the form to an iframe:

```
<iframe name="myframe" id="frame1" src="thankyou.php" style="display:none"></iframe>
<form action="../thankyou.php" method="post" target="myframe">
<input type="submit" name="DoIt" value="DoIt">
</form>
```